# Accessing passed in variable to a mixin with Jade templates

Tags: javascript, pug, express

I have a form helper mixin that I'm passing in a variable to:

```
mixin form-error(error)
  if (typeof errors !== 'undefined' && errors.#{error})
    .alert.alert-error.form-error
      =errors.#{error}.msg
```

Calling it and passing a string to it:

`mixin form_error('name')`

but am getting: `500 SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

Essentially I took everything out and it was upset over `errors.#{error}` and `=errors.#{error}.msg`

So I can't use `#{error}` after a `.`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
mixin form-error(error)
 if (typeof errors !== 'undefined' && errors[error])
  .alert.alert-error.form-error
   =errors[error].msg
```